# MSVS Installer Projects: How to reference file in source?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, installation

I have a Windows service application written in C++ that I would like users to install as a **.msi** file, so I am using [MSVS Installer Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects). The service requires a read from a file **config.cfg** to setup some parameters on each start. My current implementation installs to wherever a user specifies, but `C:\Program Files\<Install Dir>` is the default directory. In my source code I hardcoded that directory to get to the configuration file, i.e. `C:\Program Files\<Install Dir>\config.cfg` which is obviously not very portable, but it has allowed me to do some testing.

I would love to link the file relatively to the executable, but Windows Service applications set the working directory to System32, so doing something like `loadFile("config.cfg")` would expand to `loadFile("C:\Windows\System32\config.cfg")`. Installer Projects *does* [allow me to drop the config file there or any sub-folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/s2esdf4x(v=vs.100)), but this seems unideal. What is a good way of going about referencing the configuration file in source? Some things to consider:

- `%appdata%` of the installer and `%appdata%` of the service are completely different.
- Installer allows for setting registry values, but setting a string **PATH** directing to the installation folder does not seem possible.
- My application is hosting a server using a class that requires the config file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use [GetModuleFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) to get the path to the installation directory. _"...If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleFileName retrieves the path of the executable file of the current process...."_  However Service configuration is probably better in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\your_company\your_application`

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you for the function to get the path of the executable. I would really like to setup the service with the registry, but I have a [class inheriting from a framework which requires the file](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/classDcmStorageSCP.html#details) 

Comment: Note that the installation directory is not (and should not be writable) after installation so the `config.cfg` file can't be updated.

Comment: @RichardCritten I figured I could have a server and framework configuration file loaded from the installation directory but it seems I can keep the framework config read only and have some server parameters I'd like users to change in the registry. I appreciate the help and would mark the topic solved at this point if I knew how.